# Laravel returns unauthorized after login with sanctum on a react app

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I have an application split in a Laravel backend and a React frontend, API calls are made through axios.

I tried setting up authentication, first with passport, but since it was unnecessarily complicated I went with sanctum.

I followed the instructions of the documentation and managed to make a successful login. To try this I defined a protected route and tried calling it after logging in. The problem is that every call results in `401`. I checked manually and the token is present inside cookies and is sent with every request as per axios configuration.

One strange thing I noticed is that the database tables that were created while configuring sanctum are always empty. Might this be the problem?

**config/sanctum.php:**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', implode(',', [
        'localhost',
        'localhost:8000',
    ]))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['api'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

Login function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return 'ok';
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid credentials']);
        }
    }
```

config/auth.php:

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

.env:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000
```

route:

```
Route::get('/try', function(){
    return "Ciao";
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this crap package same issues even sending the cookies everything the only thing that works is with tokens.

So instead of

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

use

```
return response()->json(['token' => auth()->user()->createToken('apiToken')->plainTextToken])
```

Save the token to cookies and use it to authenticate requests. You can set expire time, delete token, create permissions for it. If you want csrf you need the requests to be on web middleware and if you want to use react it has no sense.  Belive me I've spent so much time this package has issues doesn't work as it is being said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take a look to my answer at
[Why do I get error "CSRF token mismatch". React 18 SPA with Laravel 10 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76920065/why-do-i-get-error-csrf-token-mismatch-react-18-spa-with-laravel-10-api)

You will see my so complicated issue, and how simple it was to solve it.

It is applicable to any SPA (Angular, React, Vue, etc), because the confusion of terms at the backend documentation may lead to misconfiguration and errors.
Just remember that both ends must be in HTTPS to work properly and should be a domain and subdomain (don't use Localhost) in order to share the secure cookie.