# Why do I get error "CSRF token mismatch". React 18 SPA with Laravel 10 API

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, csrf-token

I am building an SPA using React 18 connected to a Laravel 10 API, which already includes Sanctum for authentication and I installed Breeze API to generate the respective scaffolding.

I have followed the official Laravel documentation but, because it was not enough to solve this issue, I started to research with google what other developers have done do get rid of this inconvenient.
I have read about many different fixes and tried them almost all (some of them do not make sense at all or are not recommended) until I came to an old post, in github, answered by Taylor Otwell himself when Sanctum used to be called Airlock:

[image]

So, I created a domain and a subdomain in WAMP, to test this possible solution, but it is frustrating to still see the same error popping up:

[image]

As you all can see, the GET requests do not have problem but the POST requests.
For this project I installed AXIOS, but I noticed the cookies are not being sent back to the API server when posting data.

axios.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://api.localdomain',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
   },
   withCredentials: true
})
```

This is my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=localdomain
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:SjhdnO/kZ2IMWGKEdgrw+a5e1eToxvtLHsbJvwf0dAs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://api.localdomain
FRONTEND_URL=http://localdomain

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

SESSION_DOMAIN=.localdomain
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=api.localdomain
```

config/cors.php

```
'paths' => [
      'api/*',
      'login',
      'logout',
      'register',
      'user/password',
      'forgot-password',
      'reset-password',
      'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
      'user/profile-information',
      'email/verification-notification',
   ],

   'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
   'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL')],
   'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
   'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
   'exposed_headers' => [],
   'max_age' => 0,
   'supports_credentials' => true,
```

config/session.php

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),
'http_only' => true,
'same_site' => 'lax',
```

config/sanctum.php

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf('%s%s%s',
       'api.localdomain,localdomain,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
```

routes/auth.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');

Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');

Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');
```

Those routes are the ones generated with:

```
# Install Breeze and dependencies...
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install api
```

I have tried many different combinations of possible values in the .env file, cors.php and sanctum.php, but so far with no positive results.
Any help on how to make this work is really appreciated, as I have spent 3 days trying different fixes to no avail.

**EDIT: (2023/08/19)**

Taking a look at how Axios determines whether to set the response header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' or not, I came to know that the POST request (/login route) header value comes from the `document.cookies` string. However, the document.cookies is not set by Laravel (or one of its packages), despite of the fact that I changed:

```
'domain' => '.localdomain',
'secure' => false,
'http_only' => false,
'same_site' => 'lax'
```

values in config/session.php

I have tested this in my dev environment and in my local domain. The result is the same (status code 419 / CSRF token mismatch).

There is still something missing or is misconfigured in the backend side.

Comment: your `/login` path is "web" route not "api" route so it's being protected as such, I don't think sanctum has anything to do

Comment: Are you actually sending the CSRF token?  I don't see that in your code

Comment: @apokryfos axios does that automatically, but `document.cookie` is not being sent by the backend to the browser. It remains as an empty string after the `axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-token')` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after studying and testing a lot, I finally came to the answer that many may be looking for: using a ReactJS SPA authenticated by Sanctum (Laravel 10) without much changes in the Laravel configuration.

As a matter of fact, when you make a fresh installation of Laravel, it already includes the Sanctum package, so what you need to do is to install Breeze api in order to create the routes and authentication scaffolding. The whole installation process is as follows:

1. composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-api
2. cd my-api
3. composer require laravel/breeze --dev
4. php artisan breeze:install api
5. Run the migration.

That's it. You don't need to change anything in the configuration files nor in the original routes, unless you know exactly what you want to do.

The only required changes will be in the `.env` file of course. Besides that, nothing else needs to be done.

As for my case, this is how I configured my `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=localdomain
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:bla bla bla=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://api.localdomain.dom
FRONTEND_URL=https://localdomain.dom

SESSION_DOMAIN=.localdomain.dom
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

Reading the comments inside the `config/session.php` file, I realized that `HTTPS` protocol should be used (on both ends) in order to send the session cookie back to the server (as a header).

Of course!, if we are going to send a secure cookie for authentication, then it makes sense to use `HTTPS` protocol.
If not, the session cookie is not going to be sent back to the server (in the POST request) and that's why we get the 419 error.

For this to work properly, I used the **Mkcert** software to create my certificates.
[How to create locally trusted SSL certificates](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#windows)

That software saved me many headaches.

Once the virtual hosts were created with their respective certificates, my SPA ran just fine.
Again, Taylor Otwell was right when he said that for this to work, a real domain and subdomain are necessary. Localhost cannot be used because it is not a real TLD.

I hope this can help someone else, because there are many strange fixes and myths out there that really have few or nothing to do with running a SPA with Laravel Sanctum properly.

Comment: I tried many ways to make this work using `localhost` for the SPA and the API (on different ports), but it never worked (HTTP error 419 unknown status | CSRF token mismatch), hence I wonder why does the `config/sanctum.php` file have the string `localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1` in case the environment variable `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` was not initialized?  Those URLs are not supposed to work for this scenario.

Comment: If you want to create and run a `React App` directly inside `Laravel` (resources/js), it is also possible, without learning/using `Inertia` or other third party package. So that you can keep all of your source files in only one repository and you can even display blade views (optionally) without trouble.  Another advantage is that you don't need to have a domain (SPA) and sub-domain (API), nor separated repositories and more work to deploy your application.  Of course, there is a small number of steps to follow to get there, but they are simple and works fine in case someone wondered about it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems trying to handle axios request to the login route.
After 4 days of research, i finally ended up trying to downgrade axios, because everything else wasn't successfull.

**After getting down from axios v1.6.2 to v1.3.3, everything works like a charm.** No more trouble with the csrf token mismatch error. Seems like the newer version is buggy while handling csrf requests.

Maybe this hint is helpful for some of you and will save you from headaches and days of research.

Comment: Had the same problem... after a little bit of debug I noticed that in another project (axios 1.4.0) the request automatically sends the X-XSRF-TOKEN cookie also as a header, but in a new project (with ver 1.6.2) that doesn't happen and after 3 hours, this comment, and downgrading to 1.4.0, it worked.

Comment: Edit: I found that axios updated their config, now you need to add withXSRFToken. See: https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Fetch the CSRF token and set it in the cookies

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    // Make other requests here and set cookie
});
```

When making the POST request for login, ensure that the X-XSRF-TOKEN header is set with the CSRF token from the cookies. This header is automatically included by Axios when using the CSRF token cookie.

**Update:**
You also need to set withCredentials in resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: I am not using api routes as yet. This is a fresh installation of Laravel+React in a domain and subdomain, respectively. What I am trying to make work is the normal authentication, which should not be moved to the routes/api.php file, of course. I used the recommended values for the config files but it is not working yet which makes me pull my hair.

Comment: Try adding http:// before api.localdomain and localdomain in config/senctum stateful

Comment: Ali Raza, the `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` is an environment variable that holds the domains that are going to receive a session cookie in order to identify the user. This variable should not include protocol because Sanctum gets rid of it anyway.

Comment: @jgarcias I have updated the answer it looks like we need to fetch CSRF token then include it to header, to make post login request. Hope this resolve the issue.

Comment: @ Ali Raza yes, that's what I have been suspecting, however was not sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
```

to

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:8080
```

I had the same issue after changing this line it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to axios default config

```
withXSRFToken: true,
```

so you should have

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {ApiEndpoint} from "./settings.js";

const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: ApiEndpoint,
    withCredentials: true,
    withXSRFToken: true,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
});

export default axios;
```